# Duplicate Error Messages for Slug Uniqueness Check and Compatibility Issue with Email Field Validation in Sanity

Tags: validation, schema, sanity

I am facing a validation problem in my Sanity schema, specifically
related to the uniqueness check for slugs in the post type.
Additionally, there seems to be an issue with the custom validation
for the email field in the author type, resulting in unwanted
duplicate error messages.

### Code:

```js
// post.ts

import { defineField, defineType, SlugRule } from "sanity";

export default defineType({
    name: "post",
    title: "Post",
    type: "document",
    fields: [
        defineField({
            name: "title",
            title: "Post Title",
            type: "string",
            validation: (Rule) => [Rule.required().error("This field should not be left blank.")],
        }),
        defineField({
            name: "slug",
            title: "Post Slug",
            type: "slug",
            validation: (Rule: SlugRule) => [
                Rule.required().error("This field should not be left blank."),
                Rule.custom(async (value, context) => {
                    if (!value?.current) return true; // Skip custom validation if the field is empty
                    const { document, getClient } = context;
                    const client = getClient({ apiVersion: "v2022-12-07" });

                    // Check if another post already has taken this slug.
                    const params = { slug: value?.current, id: document?._id };
                    const query = "*[_type == 'post' && slug.current == $slug && _id != $id]";
                    const posts = await client.fetch(query, params);

                    if (posts.length > 0) return "This slug is already taken.";
                    return true;
                }),
            ],
            options: {
                source: "title",
                maxLength: 96,
            },
        }),
    ],
});
```

```js
// author.ts

import { StringRule, defineField, defineType } from "sanity";

export default defineType({
    name: "author",
    title: "Author",
    type: "document",
    fields: [
        defineField({
            name: "name",
            title: "Name",
            type: "string",
            validation: (Rule) => [Rule.required().error("This field should not be left blank.")],
        }),
        defineField({
            name: "email",
            title: "Email Address",
            type: "string",
            validation: (Rule: StringRule) => [
                Rule.required().error("This field should not be left blank."),
                Rule.email().error("Please enter a valid email address."),
                Rule.custom(async (value, context) => {
                    if (!value) return true; // Skip custom validation if the field is empty
                    const { document, getClient } = context;
                    const client = getClient({ apiVersion: "2022-12-07" });

                    // Check if another author already has taken this email address.
                    const params = { email: value, id: document?._id };
                    const query = "*[_type == 'author' && email == $email && _id != $id]";
                    const authors = await client.fetch(query, params);

                    if (authors.length > 0) return "This email address is already taken.";
                    return true;
                }),
            ],
        }),
    ],
});
```

### Additional Information:

I have successfully implemented similar logic with the email field in my author schema, and everything is functioning as expected. However, when I apply a similar approach to the post schema, two error messages are displayed.

### Screenshort:

[Post Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cx5tL.png)

[Author Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6nlf.png)

### Expected Output:

I only want to display my custom message for slug duplication and avoid any additional error messages.

Any assistance or insights into solving this validation problem would be highly appreciated. Thank you!